# developing formula for probability tree

Tags: probability

Hey im looking for answer for a hard probability question that i couldn't solve by myself hope you can help me.

> Running water from point O downward through a pipe system (as described in the pic below) by definition this is *level 2 system* because in every intersection there are 2 pipes.

let **p** be the probability that water flow through a single pipe and let **()** be the probability that water reach from point **O** to *level **n***.

for example **1()=**

The question is :

> Develop a fromula that describes the probability for **∞()=lim→∞()** to reach the inifinity level from level **O**.

[image: level 2 pipe system]
level 2 pipe system

Thanks in advence!

Comment: The thinking method is to solve recursively.
Need to find the connection between **()** to **-1()**.

Answer (score 0):

At level $n=k$, there are $2^k$ pipes through which the water may flow, so the probability that water flows to the next level through any pipe is $2^k p$.  This is because the probability of flowing through pipe one **or** the pipe two is the probability of flowing through pipe one **plus** the probability of flowing through pipe two.

- There is a $P_1(p)=p$ chance that the water reaches $n=1$.
- To reach $n=2$, the water must past between $O$ and $n=1$ **and** pass between $n=1$ and $n=2$, so the probability that the water reaches $n=2$ is $P_2(p)=p\left( 2p \right)$.
- To reach $n=3$, the water must past between $O$ and $n=1$ **and** pass between $n=1$ and $n=2$ **and** pass between $n=2$ and $n=3$, so the probability that the water reaches $n=3$ is $P_3(p)=p\left( 2p \right)\left(2^2p\right)$.
- $\vdots$
- The probability that the water reaches level $n=F$ is $P_F(p)=\prod_{i=0}^{F} \left(2^ip\right)$.
- $\vdots$

Hence $$P_\infty(p)=\prod_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(2^ip\right)$$

Does that make sense?

Comment: No Because for P = 1 we will obtain a probability greater than 1